# best way for bulk insertion validation laravel 5

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5, bulkinsert, bulk

i have problem validating a bulk insertion in laravel 5 the scenario that i have is as following :

a model called department that has many employees when i save a department it may have several employee belongs to it , I'm currently loops the entire employee list and validate each one before insertion is there a way in laravel 5 validator  that do this out of the box.

Comment: Do you need to validate each individual employee?

Comment: Yes I do, but what exactly is in your mind? It may work for me

Comment: If you need to validate each employee you will only be able to do that by looping through them all in some way. There is no way I know of that would eliminate that loop

Comment: I don't want to eliminate the loop,I may not phrased the question right wat I meant if there is way to do it in laravel validator where I don't need to do the loop my self.  Right now I use the validator to validate one record by one but it would be nice if there is a way to pass the list of employee to a function that do the validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5.2 there's an easy way of taking care of this kind of problems.

Validating array form input fields is much easier in Laravel 5.2. For example, to validate that each e-mail in a given array input field is unique, you may do the following:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users'
]);
```

Likewise, you may use the * character when specifying your validation messages in your language files, making it a breeze to use a single validation message for array based fields:

```
'custom' => [
    'person.*.email' => [
        'unique' => 'Each person must have a unique e-mail address',
    ]
],
```

This info is clearly explained in the docs.

Source: laravel.com

Answer (score -3):

To my knowledge there is not a way to do this in Laravel out of the box. By that I mean there is no method you can call or class you can use that will accomplish your goal.

You can create one though. Abstract the validation out into it's own class and use that.